# Might I have damaged my well pump?

Tags: pump, well

I accidentally left the hose on for 5 hours filling up the horse's trough. When I realized it, water was still flowing from the hose when I turned it off.

Water pressure seems ok in the house but I have been trying to not use any water so hopefully the well will fill back up. We have a submersible well pump.

How do I know if I burned up or damaged the pump or if it's ok?

Comment: Do have have a pressure tank?  Well pumps use the water for cooling, so if water was still pumping it should be okay.

Comment: If you're still getting water, the pump's still working. If you're still getting full pressure it sounds like it's working just fine...

Answer (score 1):

Should be fine. Where you run into problems is when the well runs out of water, especially if you don't have a low pressure cutout that shuts the pump off when/if it does. Might see a bump in your power bill, though.

Comment: Not likely to be noticeable on the electric bill. Even if it's 4kW in San Diego at $0.48/kWh, that's still less than $10 ($9.60). A 2kW pump at $0.20/kWh is only $2. Either way, probably not much compared to the monthly total for a house and horse barn.